# chart.data.datasets.push() also adds datasets to other charts in array

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an array of ChartJS objects, and for some reason using `chart.data.datasets.push({});` on a chart in the array also pushes an empty dataset to the other charts in the array.

```js
res_chartArray.forEach((chart) => {
    console.log(chart);
}); //this displays all datasets for all charts

res_chartArray[chartElement].config.data.datasets.push({data: []});
//i also tried chart.data.datasets.push()

res_chartArray.forEach((chart) => {
    console.log(chart);
}); //this displays all datasets for all charts again, it's how i checked that the dataset meant for just one chart is also pushed to other charts
```

I expected that the empty dataset will be pushed to the one chart, but also pushed for other charts in the array of charts.

0 is first chart, 1 is second chart (picture)

[image]

Comment: why doing res_chartArray[chartElement].config.data.datasets.push({data: []}); instead of simply res_chartArray[chartElement].data.datasets.push({data: []}); ?

Comment: @Zzirconium I already tried that, says so on the comment line right under that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I had 2 variables for initial data and options that is set to each chart upon creation. Everytime each chart is manipulated, the updates carry on to the other charts since they were initialized with the same initial variable ;)

```
    var defaultData = {labels: [], datasets: []};
    var defaultOptions = {};

    function addDataset(){
        chartArray.push(new Chart(ctx, {type: 'bar',
            data: defaultData,       //these two
            options: defaultOptions, //were causing the problem
        }));
    }
```

Comment: You are a saint, I was pulling my hair out over this. For anyone in the future with this, just set data: [] rather than using a var.